# Creating a method that adds an object in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

*Edited : My question was proposed wrong a caused many issues. donatePet() should simply just add an object to a list. All that was necessary was to take an object and store it in an arraylist.

```
    Input :

    Cat, CatName5, 2, Brown, rawr, 2
    Cat, Kitty, 7, Yellow, a kitty cat, 6
    Dog, DogName3, 120, Grey, This is a dog, 3
```

Ex:

```
public static void donatePet(List<Pets> petList, Pets p) 
{

    petList.add(p);

}
```

donatePet() would then be in the "test" class. (The class that will be accessing the inherited classes.)

The casting that was done by the answerer is done so that you can access methods belonging to the Pet class.

Comment: Your donatePet method should not be a member method of the Pet class. Maybe a Factory Method of another class.

Comment: what is the error and where is the test class with which you are testing the above. what do you excatly want to do as your question is not clear

Comment: So donatePet should be a member method of my test class, Rob?
Also, I added my test class. @Rob

Comment: I'm trying to take the input, call donatePet() on each line of input to create Pet objects respective to the input. I need a donatePet() method to do so. Then I need to be able to listAvailablePets, Dogs, Cats, and Other. (If they are net set to adopted)

Comment: Methods are actions you do to objects. You don't donate pets to a pet. You don't donate pets to your test bench. You donate pets, list available pets, etc. to/from a shelter, so you should make a Shelter class or a class of something that would hold multiple animals.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So shelter should hold my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `createPetType()`. In that case, store the reference of each `lineArray`.

For example `createPetType`,

```
//change method signature as per your requirement
private void createPetType(String[] lineArray) {
    //now, based on the assumption that lineArray[0] element will always have the type of Pet in it.
    if ("Dog".equalIgnoreCase(lineArray[0])) {
       //create Dog class instance
       //once you have the appropriate Pet instance
       //call donatePet method to donate
       //similarly for Cat and Other class
    }
}
```

Now, inside `donatePet()` - if you want to do something specific to the `Pet` type use `instanceof`.

For example -

```
donatePet(Pet p) {
    if (p instanceof Dog) {
       //if you are here, it means the Pet type passed to your method is of type 'Dog'
       //do whatever you want to do here
       //to cast Pet to Dog
       Dog g = (Dog) p;
       //call the methods relevant to 'g' type
       //add these instances to a list which will help you with listAvailablePets()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm now having issues adding the object to the list. For some reason, it is not recognizing petList. I have initialized it at the top of my main class by 
         `List<Object> petList = new ArrayList<Object>();`
Then in my donatePets class I call `petList.add(p);` and I get a petList cannot be resolved error.

Comment: Use `Pets` not `Object` as you are adding a `Pets` type.

Comment: Ok, whatever you do, don't follow this advice. Tirath, please learn a tiny bit of programming before advising others.

Comment: @Rob Please help me understand. Is it the advice shared in the comments or the whole thing. Not an expert and but am sure I want to learn.

Comment: Well, he said not to use it, but with some tweaking it did help me get the answer. Thanks for your help.